# Adding an image hover to a link

Tags: html, css

I have the following image with dimensions of 200px w x 100px h. Basically, I need the link to look like this

```
* link
```

where * is the image. The hover state should kick in when both the image and link are hovered on. My html & css is as follows, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<a href="#" class="current-location">Us this location</a>

.current-location {
    background-position: 0 0px;
    background: url(images/current-location.png) left top no-repeat;
    background-size: 48px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.current-location:hover {
    background-position: -24px 0px;
    background-size:  48px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Just use padding on your link. What does it all look like? Make a Fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution would be not to use images at all:

1. add a `span` in the `<a>`:

   ```
   <a href="#" class="current-location"><span>*</span> Us this location</a>
   ```
2. Style it to show on hover:

   ```
       .current-location {
          background-size: 48px 24px;
          height: 24px;
          width: 24px;
          text-decoration: none;
          position: relative;
          padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .current-location span {
             display: none;
             color: red;
             position: absolute;
             left: 0;
         }
        .current-location:hover span {
             display: inline-block;
             background-position: -24px 0px;
             background-size: 48px 24px;
             height: 24px;
             width: 24px;
         }
   ```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XFbzc/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to set *display: block* to the *.current-location* class. Also I don't think that *Us this location* will be nicely put in 24px by width.